# sql queries in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following query that selects * where display in the Zips table is equal to a column in the users table.

This works fine, but how do I select ANOTHER column from the Zips table to print it out?

`Zip.where(:display => @user.location)`

So, for example the users table has a `location` col and the zips table has a `display` and `zipcode` column. I am finding the proper row by matching `location` from users to the `display` in zips but need to pull out zipcodes from the matching entry in zips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Zip` table has the `zipcode` field:

```
@zips = Zip.where(:display => @user.location)
@zips.each do |zip|
  puts zip.zipcode
end
```

Or to put them in an array:

```
zipcodes = @zips.collect{ |zip| zip.zipcode }
```

In a view:

```
<h3>Zip Codes</h3>
<ul>
  <% @zips.each do |zip| %>
  <li><%= zip.zipcode %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```